# How to count number of occurrences of each key in a MongoDB collection efficiently (one pass?)?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, count

I'm a MongoDB noob and I have a MongoDB collection with millions of documents, each with tens of keys (average ~ 60, large variance) from a set of around 100.  I'd like to get a count of each key across the entire collection.

For example, if the documents in the collection were:

```json
{"_id":0, "foo": 0, "bar":1, "baz":2}
{"_id":1, "foo": 0, "baz":7, "qux":11, "quux":13}
{"_id":2, "foo": 1, "bar":1, "quux":3}
```

then the desired output would be:

```json
{"_id":3, "foo":3, "bar":2, "baz":2, "qux":1, "quux": 2}
```

I can "explode" the collection with `$objectToArray`, `$unwind`, `$group`, and then `$count`, but it's slow.

Is there something that could do this efficiently in one pass through the collection?  Something like,

```
[notional psuedocode]
output={}
foreach document:
  foreach key:
    if output.key exists:
      output.key+=1
    else:
      output.key=1

=> output: {key1: key1_count, ...}
```

Comment: Dynamic fields names is usually a poor design (as you see yourself). Can you change it?

Comment: Of course you can run it by a loop, but I don't expect it would be faster.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It's all dynamic sensor data of which we have no control.  Analysts query the database for data mining analysis. "Of course you can run it by a loop..." How would I do that?  I'd like to try it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "Of course you can run it by a loop..."  I know how to do this "externally" by retrieving documents via the Python connector and aggregating in Python.  Is there a way to do this completely with MongoDB?

Comment: No, the mongo shell is also a Javascript shell. I would not expect much differences between Python an Javascript.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Is there some recipe that might `$objectToArray`, `$unwind`, and then effectively update a document in a different collection?

Answer (score 0):

One of the shortest one could be this one:

```
const counts = {}
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } }
]).forEach(doc => {
   doc.data.forEach(val => {
      counts[val.k] = typeof counts[val.k] == "undefined" ? val.v : counts[val.k] + val.v;
   })
})
```

I tried to find solution of `$objectToArray`, `$group` but most likely it will not work, because the size of document is limited to 16 MiBytes. Having "millions of documents" this limit will certainly exceeded.

Comment: I used `counts[val.k] = typeof counts[val.k] == "undefined" ? 1 : counts[val.k] + 1;` and it works, but the "millions of documents" makes the wait time forever, so far.  I inserted a `$limit` to test and `counts` looked reasonable.  I did implement a `$unwind`, `$group` with `$count`, and that does work, and maybe that's the best that can be expected, but it's still slow.  I don't think I'll be doing this "collection field overview" often since it's so slow.